# Political Preferences of Software Engineers in USA?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, political-spectrum

I'm interested in a breakdown of the political preferences of software engineers in the United States.

I read a comment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342903/well-always-endeavor-to-do-whats-right-well-try-to-do-it-better-next-time/342941?noredirect=1#comment443445_342903):

> The majority of developers are also overwhelmingly left leaning

The only readily available information I could find was from 2008, and only referenced "engineers" in general, showing them as conservative leaning:

[image]

I'd love to see something more up to date. I'd love to see something which addressed software engineers in finer granularity.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here. It seemed more on topic here than in the programmers stack exchange, but if I should be asking elsewhere I'd be happy to move the question.

Comment: Should fit here.  Very surprised by the corporate lawyers, by the way.

Comment: @gerrit There is some interesting stuff in the graph. Apparently Auto Dealer is the most conservative profession, and Travel Agent is the most unbiased. Maybe I should start going to my travel agent to get my news ;)

Comment: This site traffics in mostly software specialists (more than polticos) and it slants leftward on most issues.  Not the fine tuning you asked for.

Comment: @gerrit might be a US specific thing, there's a [fairly good argument](http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/trial-lawyers-find-that-generosity-to-democrats-pays-big-dividends/article/38945) that the Democratic party is in the pocket of lawyers and frequently makes laws designed to enrich them. This isn't a partisan jab, the GOP has tons of industries it loves to pander to with crony capitalism as well.

Comment: Falling into either side of the political spectrum is not the same as using preconceptions based on political leanings to filter or disregard facts and/or data.  The fact that people may align on one side or the other does not equate to a bias.  The degree to which they don't attempt to be aware of their leanings and make sure to try and be objective would be bias. That's why, for instance, the fact that journalists or scientists align one way or the other does not mean their work is automatically biased, because their professional standards, if followed, specifically guard against it.

Comment: @JonathanMee - it's easy to be unbiased as a set of individuals when the set consists of zero individuals (realistically, there's almost no more travel agents - they were Expidia-ed away).

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - 1950s called, they want their journalists who actually tried to report the news instead of influence them back. Hell, I heard journalists openly calling Trump "enemy" around inauguration. A vast majority of journalists in the west don't care about anything but furthering their political preferences, and aren't even all that coy about it anymore (it was the same in 18-19th century; but they were honest about their partisan leanings, and less overwhelmingly in the same corner than now)

Comment: @user4012 There you go, a new solution. The 3 Travel Agents left should stop trying to survive against travel sites and just start doing journalism. It's like a reinvention of the profession!

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I understand your statement. If you're interested in more context you can check out the comment this question is responding to. Would you recommend I rephrase the question somehow to improve clarity?

Comment: @user4012 - nonsense and propaganda.  Which journalists, and in what context?  Pundits, or actual journalists?  "Enemy" in terms of journalists supposed to be reporting on facts, and the Trump faction waging war on objective fact, or they just don't like him.  That's crap and nonsense.

Comment: @JonathanMee - no need to reword.  That was a "something to keep in mind" comment.  As you can see by commenters, like user4012, some people feel like if facts and history don't conform to your desires, it must be because of bias, and assume that bias MUST exist because they don't like the results.

Comment: Yeah, bias is probably the wrong word I just couldn't think of anything better. I was using the word in the way that media outlets are accused of bias which could be said "association" perhaps? Who knows how you'd get data on this though? I'd love to see it as a question on the developer survey some year, cause I'd be so interested in the results.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, re: your earlier comment about political alignment not = bias--that's literally true but maybe not much of a practical difference.  Bias is a human trait.  Individuals are biased more or less, but the distribution isn't tied to party.  If anything, it's related to distance from the center in either direction.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm with you. If you feel there's a better word for the title please edit. I admittedly didn't know what word to use.

Comment: There are some theories that there is a relationship between a liberal leaning and high language cognitive ability (which would explain why programmers and lawyers, for example, would tend toward liberalism, and engineers more toward conservatism).  See http://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/markusk/Kemmelmeier_2008_PAID.pdf

Comment: @fixer1234 - That's why you teach and train on journalistic standards and scientific statistical validation.  You recognize that it is inherent, and you build in safeguards to eliminate or minimize the effect.  If I'm personally biased but professionally objective, then my personal bias is irrelevant.  People pretend that professional journalists and organizations don't actually follow these safeguards, and pretend that crap news sources are the same as ones with standards.  This is part of our problem when evaluating credibility of the final product - not recognizing that some have standards.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, absolutely.  If only that could be applied to postings on this site.

Comment: I won't be able to touch this until tonight, but ANES data has a profession field. So we could look at partisanship by profession. If someone beats me to this, remember to weight the responses!

Comment: @indigochild I'm interested. [tim's answer](http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/15340/11420) is the best thus far, but it certainly leaves a lot unknown. I'll make sure to hold for your response before accepting anything.

Comment: @user4012 how old were you during the 1950s? You are naive if you believe that there was only "pure news" back then any more than there is today. News teams have *always* have points of views.

Comment: As for travel agents being more liberal, it makes sense in that travel agents...travel. A lot. It's been shown that those exposed to more cultures and ethnicities tend to be more liberal in their political perspectives. (FYI, there are still a lot of travel agents out there...albeit a lot fewer than a decade ago).

Comment: @blip I think the point is that there wasn't a goal to provide sensationalist news in the 1950s, so no one preyed upon the political sensitivities of a group. Spinning the news to stir up a reaction in one party or the other creates a demand for more news on the topic.

Comment: Ummm... I'm not sure where you're getting the source, "It's been shown that those exposed to more cultures and ethnicities tend to be more liberal in their political perspectives." But if you look at the graph travel agents are the most *neutral*.

Comment: @blip - No, being not exposed to life under socialism tends to make people more liberal in their perspectives. Most immigrants from socialist countries are fare more exposed to more cultures and even ethnicities than most hardcore Western liberals (I lived on 3 continents and visited 4, you?), but reject liberalism for its endless fascination with murder cult of socialism.

Comment: @JonathanMee - in that vein, is your question confined to *western* software developers? There's likely a marked difference between those indoctrinated by a combination of liberal Western academia and Richard Stallman; and those who weren't. As well as between millenials who code and people who learned to code 50 years ago, when it mattered what your code quality was and not whether you're holding Double Plus Notgood political views.

Comment: @user4012 Yeah the question specifically calls out "United States" It's also tagged as such. I'm mostly curious what potential population of our membership may have been offended by Joel Spolsky's Meta Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @JonathanMee - gotcha. Although, wasn't the whole point Joel was so artfullly trying to make was "don't assume that everyone contributing to or interested in StackOverflow is like you"? Which includes programmers from Russia, Israel, Kenya, and Poland.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53147/discussion-between-user4012-and-jonathan-mee).

Comment: @user4012 I realize you like to remind everyone you lived under some flavor of socialism. I have no idea what that has to do with the conversation here but thanks for reminding us once again less we forget.

Comment: @JonathanMee - Looks like the profession information from ANES is confidential and not available to the general public. Sorry!

Comment: Looks like those who work in hands-on trades or in the hard sciences tend to be more conservative and those dealing with the intangible are more liberal.  This would have been my guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Verdant Labs](http://verdantlabs.com/politics_of_professions/index.html) has data on the political leanings sorted by profession, based on campaign contributions.

For software engineers:

[image]

For other IT professions:

[image]

Others have similar data based on campaign contributions (eg [Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.com/charts-show-the-political-bias-of-each-profession-2014-11?IR=T)). I would prefer polls asking the actual political leanings based on professions, but I couldn't find any data on that.

Comment: Seems as reliable as anything we're going to get. Obviously we could just have this overwhelming majority of developers who simply do not contribute, but it seems reasonable that there would be approximately the same percentage of non-contributing engineers on each side of the aisle.

Comment: +1 because it's the best attempt at a proxy so far. However, it's not a good measurement. Income will vary wildly between professions, making some people far more able (and likely) to donate to campaigns. Professions also are proxies for a lot of other socio-economic things, so there a lot of confounding factors.

Comment: @indigochild I don't quite see how the income differential between professions would matter here.  You might get a larger percentage of doctors contributing than fry cooks, but within each profession that would not matter.  The biggest critique that I have is that in resent political cycles there have been concerted efforts to bring in small donors on the left while the right has relied mostly on the traditional big money contributions.  That should be something we could model for and create a correction factor if it had a significant effect.

Comment: A possible problem with this approach (not sure if this data compensates for that) is that political contributions might get very skewed by a few extra rich CEOs (and many software CEOs are liberal, so if that's the case they could easily dominate the data). Another problem is that many people are libertarian rather than liberal - they basically have nobody to contribute to, so they aren't counted here but they don't necessarily agree with liberals on some things. Totally agree that polls would be far better.

Comment: @Ukko - the issue your comment raised may be worth factoring out into an independent question on Politics.SE.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is not meant to be definitive proof that most software developers are left leaning, but I do want to show some high correlations between your average software developer and your typical American democrat.

First, the average software developer is a young person. In the 2016 Stack Overflow developer survey (which isn't perfect, but is again this answer isn't going for perfect) [Over 50% of software developers are under 30 years old](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#developer-profile-age). A 2016 from the Harvard institute of Politics show that [Clinton was polling at 61% of people under 30](http://iop.harvard.edu/youth-poll/harvard-iop-spring-2016-poll). The [NYT exit polls](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/11/08/us/politics/election-exit-polls.html) also show that Clinton won people under 30 by around a 20 point lead.

Second, most software development centers are in big cities. Silicon valley, NYC, San Francisco, Seattle, Austin, Houston, etc. These are all large urban areas that reliably vote blue.

Finally, and this is entering into total personal speculation space, I think the paradigms of software engineering tend be similar to a liberal point of view. Specifically, developers like to centralize; why write the same code twice? Why have the same data in 2 places? etc. Conservatives tend to be more about personal freedom, states right, and reduction of a large centralized government. (Note: I'm not taking a stance on which one is right or wrong here, please don't get into a war in comments).

Remember though that all I've really shown here is high correlation, not causation. That being said, when you roll the dice I think this will show why your average software developer is likely to be a liberal.

Comment: I think you go real far off the rails relying on the age of the resumes on SO developers.

Comment: @Andy Its not the age on resumes, its the self-reported age from people who took the SO developer survey a year ago. And I totally agree, its not perfect, but its a good estimate. You'll find similar results if you look at demographic reports from big tech companies like Google and Apple: the average developer tends to be young, under 30.

Comment: I contest that the survey is even a good estimate (self reporting is notoriously unreliable), and focusing on big tech companies is going to skew things too.  And you have the same problem focusing on one or two big companies.  There are over 600,000 software engineers in the US; MS employs ~120,000 people worldwide, and only 40% are software engineers.  They employ 71K in the US, and assuming that 40% holds in the US (it may not), that means they employ 28K engineers, or less than 5% of the entire US software development workforce.

Comment: @Andy Like I mentioned in my answer multiple times... my stats are not perfect at all. That being said there are many sources out there that show most developers are relatively young. Even outside of big companies. Computer science as an industry only exploded relatively recently, which is why it gets this heavy skew towards young people.